# Alternative to enum in C# - nested

Tags: c#, enums, static, c#-6.0

Came across this interesting article:

[Alternative to enum by Ardalis](http://ardalis.com/enum-alternatives-in-c)

How can I make it possible to have nested classes within the class.

Suppose, we have different statuses for each role: Author, Editor.

> Author: Seasoned, Elite
>
> Editor: Approved, Occassional

how can I access the value as:

> `Role.Author.Seasoned.Value`
>
> `Role.Editor.Approved.Value`

Thanks

Comment: why you don't want to use Enum ?

Comment: In order to write custom logic and enable nesting for specific business cases.

Comment: Each role should contain collection of statuses, I don't see other way around it.

Comment: You are asking for a plain class that has two properties which behaves like enums.  Just make it so, there is no good reason in corrupting the Role class to be something else than an enum alternative.  Fwiw, enum types exist to make code fast and memory-efficient.  This isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the question. If you want to have nested classes, use *nested classes*. Starting with the design from the article you linked to, you would get:

```
public class Role
{
    public static class Author
    {
        public static Role Seasoned {get;} = new Role(0, "Seasoned author");
        public static Role Elite {get;} = new Role(1, "Elite author");
    }

    public static class Editor
    {
        public static Role Approved {get;} = new Role(2, "Approved editor");
        public static Role Occassional {get;} = new Role(3, "Occassional editor");
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    private Role(int val, string name) 
    {
        Value = val;
        Name = name;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Role> List()
    {
        return new[]{Author.Seasoned,Author.Elite,Editor.Approved,Editor.Occassional};
    }

    public Role FromString(string roleString)
    {
        return List().FirstOrDefault(r => String.Equals(r.Name, roleString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public Role FromValue(int value)
    {
        return List().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Value == value);
    }
}
```